# Using ArcMap's report system on large scale?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing

I'm trying to set up a reporting system based off two layers - point and polygon feature classes.

The system would run this report on each polygon that had a value in a specific field (polygons that didn't need to be ran would be null) and select all points within that polygon and spit out the necessary information in a pdf.

More advanced uses of this would be for someone to type in a specific polygon they needed and it would spit out the points within that polygon.

Comment: You've tagged this as `python` - do you have any experience programming Python? Have you looked at the [arcpy cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000)? You could set up a search cursor to iterate through the polygons, then select by location to find the points, then export the information you need. But you'll need to ask a more focussed question - no-one is going to write the whole thing for you!

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about the site.  You make no mention of ArcPy but added a Python tag so I am assuming that you are looking for coding ideas, which makes this far too broad for our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Sorry, This will eventually use python but for the time being I'm just trying to get the report stuff all setup so when we do use python everything runs a little smoother.

Comment: Are you stuck when you try to use the report writer of ArcGIS for Desktop?  If so, precisely where?  Please use the [edit] button to revise your question.